# Переустановка android

Tags: gcc, android

Всем привет. Возможно ли переустановить андроид? Если да то как?

Answer (score 1):

Переустановить можно. Кинуть прошивку на карту памяти,установить cwm (следующие действия из cwm),сделать необходимые вайпы,установить прошивку,установить гапсы если нужен маркет.

Укажите ваше устройство. http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showforum=268 выбирайте фирму и ищите свою модель, либо в поиск "<фирма модель> прошивка"

Comment: Вот сайт http://lg-phone-firmware.com/index.php?id_mod=12 как я узнаю какя у меня прошивка там куча всего.Я только знаю что у меня jealy been 4.1.2 и все!

Comment: я бы поставил вот это http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=353120&st=20#entry15964938но если хочешь сток то любая из этих последняя самая новая(они для снг а значит с русским языком и нашими частотами в радиомодуле)http://lg-phone-firmware.com/index.php?id_mod=12#cis

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 0):

Можно и не заходя в телефон (даже залоченный).
ПК + USB-кабель + ПО для прошивки и + естественно, сама прошивка.